# Is there an R function that allows me to combine 2 graphs?

Tags: arrays, graph, pie-chart, pca

#I'm trying to do a taste wheel, like the Meilgaard wheel.
I'm not trying to do anything complex I only want to plot together a pie chart and a PCA plot.
I would like to have the piechart bigger than the PCA graph.

I would like to plot the pie graph with both the two PCA graphs or with the fviz_pca_biplot.

The following is the PCA:

```
principal4<-PCA(ExpertWine2,scale.unit = T,ind.sup = NULL,quanti.sup =29:30,quali.sup =1,graph = T,axes = c(1,2),ncp = 3)
fviz_pca_biplot(principal4)
```

The following is the pie chart:

```
slices <- c(10, 10, 10, 10)
lbls <- c("acidity", "freshness", "sweetness", "corposity")
coloris = c("gold", "cyan", "indianred1", "burlywood4")
cake=pie(slices, labels = lbls, init.angle=45, main="Pie Chart of tastes",col=coloris)
```

Answer (score -1):

There are multiple packages aimed at solving this. It will depend on whether you as using a base r plotting implementation or something like ggplot.

I would reccomend looking at bentobox (strict positioning), patchwork (auto positioning) and cowplot (somewhere in the middle). Patchwork is primarily aimed at ggplot but the other two should work with any plotting method.

bento box:
https://github.com/PhanstielLab/BentoBox

patchwork:
https://patchwork.data-imaginist.com/

cowplot:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cowplot/vignettes/introduction.html

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to have a plot that overlaps the other in order to have colours on the back of the arrows. It seems that these packages are only useful to put a plot next to the other.

Comment: I believe with bento box the locations of the plots can be specified exactly for every plot and so two plots could be specified with these parameters. (i.e. set the plot positions to overlap though this will require a manual setting of the size).

Cowplot also allows for plots to be placed atop one another exactly (i.e. it may not solve the different sizes issue). See the final example here:
https://wilkelab.org/cowplot/articles/aligning_plots.html

You are definitely correct that this is not a feature of patchwork.